# Convert javascript prompt to html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to convert some javascript that gives the user a prompt into an html form that displays the output in a span. I've been searching the net but haven't found a way to do it that I can understand.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nickykw/tMXmj/15/

I'd like the output of the script to be displayed in the "outp" span. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Put the code in there. What is jsfiddle's down? Your question won't mean anything.

Comment: And reduce that to a minimally-reproducible demo, that shows your problem and doesn't require (hopefully) quite so much JavaScript to negotiate in order to solve. Is the basic problem how to get the guess/user-entered value into a text element in the document somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you if you are allowed to use jQuery and you name your controls. If you are not allowed to use jQuery I hope you get the idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit-button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = parseInt($('.submit-input').val());
        $('#outp').html(num2Letters(number));       
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2P7H/